# docusign api test account login demo site

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the Rest V2 API to create an envelope with a document in it.  We then redirect the user to the page for them to complete the document (drag tag etc).  using the demo server and our developer login we get a message saying the user has been logged out due to inactivity.  On the production site with a production account it works OK.  We can log into the demo site without issue with our account.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the new version (which goes on demo.docusign.net first), that bug should be addressed by now.  The great news is that no production servers were affected and by the time the new version will make it to production the bug will be fixed.  I believe demo servers will get the fix tomorrow.

Thanks for choosing DocuSign API!